# How to get the data of a specific row on a GridView on behind code and pass it to another webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have the code show below. I click an edit button and in the code behind i get the row number but how do i get the values of the fields? I want to pass the data of the fields to another page ? And also What is the best way to pass the values of the fields to another webform : "SecondPage.aspx?Id=" + id or using Session or is there a better way?

.aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="100">
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "vFormReport2.aspx?id=" & CType(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fldEmployeeID"), String)%>'  Text="Edit" />
    </ItemTemplate>     
 </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldEmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldAbsentDate" HeaderText="AbsentDate" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldAbsentCode" HeaderText="AbsentCode" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldRuleViolationWarningType" HeaderText="Rule Violation Warning" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldRuleViolationIssueDate" HeaderText="Rule Violation Issue Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldLOAEndDate" HeaderText="LOA End Date" />
</Columns>
```

.cs code

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If SDS2.Text = "0" Then
        Dim SqlDataSource1 As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
        SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1"
        Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1)
        SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "your string here "
        'SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] WHERE [fldEmployeeID]=38"
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID], [fldAbsentDate], [fldAbsentCode]"
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
        GridView1.DataBind()         
    Else
        Dim SqlDataSource2 As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
        SqlDataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource2"
        Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource2)
        SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = "your string here"
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] WHERE [fldAbsentDate] BETWEEN '7-03-2014' AND '8-21-2014' ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID]"
        'SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID], [fldAbsentDate], [fldAbsentCode]";
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2
        GridView1.DataBind()
        sqldatasource2click = True
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging

    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim int As Integer = 0
    Session("counter") = Convert.ToString(int)

    If Session("counter") = "0" Then
        GridView1.PageIndex = 0
    End If
    SDS2.Text = "1"
    Dim SqlDataSource2 As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
    SqlDataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource2"
    Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource2)
    SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = "Your String here"
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] WHERE [fldAbsentDate] BETWEEN '7-03-2014' AND '8-21-2014' ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID]"
    'SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID], [fldAbsentDate], [fldAbsentCode]";
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2
    GridView1.DataBind()        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you want to edit an Employee record.
I'm assuming that this GridView is only a subset of the Employee data, so you will want to retrieve the entire record in the form that you redirect to, so you only need to pass the fldEmployeeID.
Simply change your Edit control to a hyperlink to pass the fldEmployeeID to your form:-

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "vFormReport2.aspx?id=" & CType(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fldEmployeeID"), String)%>'  Text="Edit" />
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

There is no need for RowIndex or any code-behind (which is VB, by the way).
Using a hyperlink is also a lot quicker that the postback that you get with a row command.

Comment: How do I handle the rows that have empty fields ? because then I have the error : Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid

Comment: When or why do you have rows in the database with empty fields?

Comment: I was getting it because on some fields there is a null value. But i actually could passed the values without using the CType method. But i took a different way of developing the application as i updated above. Now I am Binding the data on code behind. How can i achieve the same as you showed me but with this new code ? I would appreciate if you can help me

Comment: Never mind it Works! But is it Ok to pass the values as url string like this: NavigateUrl='<%# "FormReport2.aspx?id=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fldEmployeeID")%>' Without converting it to string as you did ?